# app_offline and index.html for API backed React SPA

Tags: reactjs, iis, .net-core, react-router

I have a React SPA which talks to a WebAPI backend. Everything lives from the same IIS website and we have a couple of rewrite rules to send all requests to index.html. This works ok but when I put the `app_offline.htm` file in the root, while the API correctly shuts down (returns a 503), the server is still serving the index.html rather than the app_offline.htm, which simply shows a login page with a server error.

My web.config is as follows. I am sure everything is in the right place but still the index.html is served before everything else. I have tried the "runAllManagedModulesPerRequest=true" but it does not work. I have a feeling that the UrlRewrite rule is just getting the content from the index.html and serving it overriding the app_offline...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="api/*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="React Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
            <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(/api/)(.*)" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(/content/)(.*)" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(/static/)(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE:
Just to clarify the web.config above. The purpose is to be able to use urls like "http://blah.com/customer/3/orders". What happens here is that the above URL will still get the index.html, then React Router will work it magic based on the rest of the URL and load (with API calls) the customer with id=3 and show their orders.
If I have the app_offline.htm doc, the index will still load but then the API calls to customer etc will fail (which is expected). What I want is the index.html to not be served if the app_offline file is present.

Comment: That is expected. The offline page only applies to ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, but not IIS. You have to stop the IIS site if that's what you wanted.

Comment: If you enable failed request tracing, you will notice that the 503 error is returned from asp.net core.ModuleName="AspNetCoreModuleV2", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="503". So if the reuqest didn't trigger the handler, it may keep returning static file. If you would like to find the root cause, please enable failed request tracing and check the log.

Comment: @JokiesDing, the 503 is expected because the app_offline.htm is there. I would expect the app_offline to be served before the index.html

Comment: Have you captured and check the failed request tracing log for the abnormal response ? If we can find the root cause, we should be able to fix this. The IIS intergrated pipeline should handle app_offline.htm all the time because asp.net module is part of IIS integrated pipeline even when you server a static file. I'm also curious in which condition the app_offline will not be triggered.

Comment: I will try that. I have updated to show why this happens (I think). Basically the URL /a/b/c gets rewritten to serve the index.html, and this is bypassing the app_offline. I think the API is a red herring, I simply think that a React Router app either needs something else to cope with that or just does not work